# Excel formular to C# code

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'd like to convert an excel spreadsheet to a component of c# code. To get it goin' I like to get all cells of a sheet containing fomulars into c# via interop. In the c# module I'd like to solve the defined fomulars with different values replacing the cell references in the fomular. Is there a framework where I can for example convert a "SUM($C3 : $C5)" from excel to a "var sum = c3 + c4 + c5;" or semilar formulars?

regards gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you'll do repeatedly or just one time?

We're using www.spreadsheetgear.com to manipulate Excel spreadsheets from C# and it works wonderfully. Our needs are different, so you should study the API to see if it gives you access to the text of the forumulas, but I think it might.

No affiliation - just a satisfied customer.

Comment: Getting the formular out of the spreadsheet is not the problem. This is already accomplished via office-interop. The result is the fomular in string format. I want to replace references like "C22" with another value and then solve the formular without excel. Since I'm already in c# code I'd like to solve the formular there.

Comment: Oh I see it can evaluate calculations given to it. This might be a solution but since it's not free I think I could not use it. But it gets the solved.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for an expression evaluator in C#.

Google found a few that I think you should look at:

- The [Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator](http://flee.codeplex.com) on Codeplex.
- [ILCalc](http://ilcalc.codeplex.com) on CodePlex - "This project was inspired by the FLEE project, but written in different, much easier way."
- [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) is another one on CodePlex - evaluates custom functions and works with Unicode, which might be important for you. There is a related [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sota_expression_evaluator.aspx).
- [There's this C# Expression Evaluator article](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/a-c-expression-evaluator) by Jonathan Wood.
- There's one in the [Spring.net Framework](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html).
- A [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/eval3.aspx) by Pascal Ganaye.
- Or you can work on your own starting with the [DynCalc](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/11/4513.aspx) example by Bart de Smet.

You might also need implementations of all those built-in Excel functions. There's a library with all the financial functions re-implemented in F# by Luca Bolognese - find it [on MSDN](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/FinancialFunctions).

Answer (score 1):

More power than what you need, but with some luck only a thin interface wrapper is needed to pump data out of execl into formula engine:

> FormulaEngine is a .NET assembly that
>   enables you to add formula support to
>   your application. It takes care of
>   parsing and evaluating formulas,
>   tracking their dependencies, and
>   recalculating in natural order. The
>   formula syntax and much of the
>   engine's functionality are direct
>   replicas of Excel ensuring a low
>   learning curve for users.

Link: [FormulaEngine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/FormulaEngine.aspx)

---

Update: I recently started a similar python library: [pycel](https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ActiveMesa X2C](http://activemesa.net/x2c), which does precisely that. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of said product.)

Comment: Fixed the URL..

Comment: Thanks - updated link appears fine; deleted my earlier comment and removed my downvote.